# Grails Resources Plugin Not Finding /lib/ folder after upgrade

Tags: grails, grails-resources-plugin

I've recently upgraded a grails app to 2.4.3 and in the process upgraded the resources plugin to 1.2.14. I realize the assets plugin is preferred at this point, but I cannot make the switch just yet. I have the following defined in my ApplicationResources.groovy

```
modules = {
  core {
    resource url: '/js/main.js', disposition: 'head'
    resource url: '/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css', disposition: 'head'
    ... more here
  }
}
```

When I run the app, I get the following:

```
| Error 2015-02-01 23:13:40,005 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
```

If you look at the image I've attached, you can see that this file is indeed in the correct place, and this worked with an older version of the resources plugin.

[image: directory structure of static resources]

Comment: Hi, Gregg try to use another folder(not lib). I think problem in it.

Comment: I've tried different folder names, all giving me the same error.

Comment: Same issue here with Grails 2.5.3

Answer (score 1):

The Grails Resources plugin uses the `grails.resources.adhoc.patterns` and `grails.resources.adhoc.includes` values in `Config.groovy` to determine which resources to process. Perhaps this behavior changed across versions and you need to add the lib directory like so:

```
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*', '/lib/bootstrap/css/*']
grails.resources.adhoc.includes = ['/images/**', '/css/**', '/js/**', '/plugins/**', '/lib/bootstrap/css/**']
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a very old question, but thought my finding would helpful to someone. If we place `grails.resources.resourceLocatorEnabled = false` in `Config.groovy` file then it should work. No need to add `grails.resources.adhoc` property.